# How to declare the ID of a view inside an ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist

I´m working with a layout with hundreds of ID, so I need a way of declaring several id. I tried to do that, but the app crashed.

```
public class middleScreenfragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentMiddleScreenfragmentBinding binding;
    List<ProgressBar> progressBarList = new ArrayList<ProgressBar>();
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMiddleScreenfragmentBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            progressBarList.add(progressBar);
        

        progressBarList.get(0).getRootView().findViewById(R.id.id_1);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create ```ProgressBar``` programmatically or what? ```ProgressBar progressBar;``` is not assigned and this line ```progressBarList.get(0).getRootView()``` of course will crash.

Comment: I´m trying declaring id, like progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.id_1). I want doing that inside a ArrayLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get crash is because the `progressBar` is not properly created. You are just adding null Object into your `progressBarList`.

So to solve the Exception, you have to assign a `ProgressBar` to it:

```java
public class MiddleScreenfragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentMiddleScreenfragmentBinding binding;
    List<ProgressBar> progressBarList = new ArrayList<ProgressBar>();
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        // Assign progressBar so that it is not null
        progressBar = new ProgressBar(getContext());
        ...
    }

}
```

And to assign ID programmatically, you can make use of this function [`View.generateViewId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#generateViewId()):

> Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int). This value will not collide with ID values generated at build time by aapt for R.id.

And you can use it like this:

```java
public class MiddleScreenfragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentMiddleScreenfragmentBinding binding;
    List<ProgressBar> progressBarList = new ArrayList<ProgressBar>();
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMiddleScreenfragmentBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          progressBar = new ProgressBar(getContext());
          // Set ID programmatically of the newly created Progress Bar
          progressBar.setId(View.generateViewId());
          progressBarList.add(progressBar);
        }

        ...

        return view;
    }

}
```